# how to push value in to object's property dynamically in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, push

I want to push the value into array based on the property value recieved from frontend using mongoose.

Schema:

```
authencity: {
        fake: [],
        notSure: [],
        authentic: [],
      }
```

Now I want to push the value into array based on property value received from frontend

```
const result = await News.findOneAndUpdate({ name: newsName }, { $push: { `authencity[${authencityType}]`: email } });
```

authencityType could be anything like fake, notSure, authentic based on this value I want to insert the value into respective array.

Sample Data:

```
Sample Document :{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f0af1e09a724b06c86bfaec"
    },
    "authencity": {
        "fake": [],
        "notSure": [],
        "authentic": []
    },
    "name": "Rajasthan deputy CM Sachin Pilot\u2019s supporters come to Gurugram resort, call police summon a joke",
    "description": "",
    "url": "https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiqwFodHRwczovL3d3dy5oaW5kdXN0YW50aW1lcy5jb20vaW5kaWEtbmV3cy9yYWphc3RoYW4tZGVwdXR5LWNtLXNhY2hpbi1waWxvdC1zLXN1cHBvcnRlcnMtY29tZS10by1ndXJ1Z3JhbS1yZXNvcnQtY2FsbC1wb2xpY2Utc3VtbW9uLWEtam9rZS9zdG9yeS1ZQ1BQVDFlandtb1RoQXJaRXVabmNOLmh0bWzSAa0BaHR0cHM6Ly9tLmhpbmR1c3RhbnRpbWVzLmNvbS9pbmRpYS1uZXdzL3JhamFzdGhhbi1kZXB1dHktY20tc2FjaGluLXBpbG90LXMtc3VwcG9ydGVycy1jb21lLXRvLWd1cnVncmFtLXJlc29ydC1jYWxsLXBvbGljZS1zdW1tb24tYS1qb2tlL3N0b3J5LVlDUFBUMWVqd21vVGhBclpFdVpuY05fYW1wLmh0bWw?oc=5",
    "category": "general",
    "language": "en",
    "country": "in",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Received Data : email : abcd@gmail.com authencityType could be fake or notSure or authentic

I want to push value in specific array based on authencityType recieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newColumn = `authencity.${authencityType}`;

const result = await News.findOneAndUpdate({ name: newsName }, { $push: { [newColumn]: email } }, { new: true });
```

Here, I have created a dynamic string to construct a column name using template literal and then enclosed it with [], so mongo will consider this a column name

Comment: Pls do consider of explaining your code and how it would help, so that others can get benefited from this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your path using [the dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents) instead of square brackets:

```
`authencity.${authencityType}`
```

For instance `authenticity.fake`

try:

```
const result = await News.findOneAndUpdate({ name: newsName }, { $push: { `authencity.${authencityType}`: email } }, { new: true });
```

Also note that in mongoose's findOneAndUpdate version you need to pass [new: true](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) parameter in order to return modified document

Comment: @AdityaVyas can you show a sample document and the data you're trying to update?

Comment: @AdityaVyas you're building your query based on `newsName` but you said that the payload contains only `email`. Is that correct?

Comment: `newName` I am taking from params.

Comment: Are you able to find your document by `newName`? What's the value of `result`?

Comment: Yes, its the full document

Comment: @AdityaVyas have you tried with `{new: true}` like in my modified example?

Comment: @AdityaVyas it will return the modified version (returns the old one by default)

Comment: ```
const newColumn = `authencity.${authencityType}`;

const result = await News.findOneAndUpdate({ name: newsName }, { $push: { newColumn: email } }, { new: true });
    console.log(result);
```
This is also not working for me

Comment: `{ $push: { [newColumn]: email } }`, otherwise you have fixed value `newColumn`